# How to automatically set TextField()'s width

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, text

I'm trying to set the width of a Textfield() object based on it's string content that I have set-
Is there a way to dynamically set this once the string has been sent to the object?

I have:

```
var t1:TextField = new TextField()
t1.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
t1.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;           
t1.text = "some string that i would want to render";            
t1.textColor = 0x000000;
t1.cacheAsBitmap = true;
addChild(t1);
```

Thanks for any suggestions...
jml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TextField.autoSize](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#autoSize)?

**edit:**

You should read the documentation correctly, it's a member variable that actually needs to be set. I'll give you a quick example on how this works:

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.text     = 'Some text.';
tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
tf.x = ( stage.stageWidth  - tf.width ) / 2;
tf.y = ( stage.stageHeight - tf.height ) / 2;
```

Alternatively you can also align the text field first and use `TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER` to keep it aligned in the center.

Comment: sweet.
thanks for this answer.  I didn't see it in the autocomplete options.

Comment: How did I miss that... it's like the 5th property in the live docs

Comment: hm; actually- it doesn't look like this works... i'll post my code in another answer.

Comment: Just edit your question, I'll update my post then to reply you :)

Comment: thanks for help on the site etiquette and the docs.  to be honest i find the adobe docs to be of the most off-putting manuals in existance... but in the future i'll try to do more research into the way in which you have to populate the vars.  i had previously set a variable and got an error (thought it was a bool).

Comment: The LiveDocs are actually (imo) one of the best manuals for programming languages, and it gives a lot information about a member's syntactical data; `autoSize:String  [read-write]` for example says that its name is `autoSize`, and it's a `String` that can be both read and written to. And of course the text gives information for example what exact values you can set (in this case there are even constants for the 4 values).

Answer (score 1):

```
t1.text = "Some text";
t1.width = t1.textWidth + 5;
t1.height = t1.textHeight + 5;
```

Why the `+ 5`? Because Adobe sucks and adds an internal gutter around your stuff. Per the docs this is supposed to be 2px per side, but it's actually slightly more, so you add another +1 for good measure.

Comment: i have to admit tho- the textwidth thing works just fine and you don't have to add in another import.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using the getCharBoundaries() method (it returns a rectangle surrounding a character at a specified index). Use that to get the rectangle from the first and last chars and set the width to the difference of those rectangles.

Pretty convoluted, there's got to be a better way, but if not this should work.

Comment: oh great!
no; i don't mind this at all... i think the general rule w/r/t working with flex and flash is that you have to accept the convoluted nature of it.  :)

Comment: hm; can you give an example?  here is what i am trying:

   t1.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
   t1.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
   var st1:String ="some string that i would like to render"; 
   t1.text = st1;
   t1.width = t1.getCharBoundaries(st1.length)[1];
   t1.textColor = 0x000000;
   t1.cacheAsBitmap = true;
   addChild(t1);